# maximal sequence of equal elements in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, equals

I have for homework the exercise: Write a program that finds the maximal sequence of equal elements in an array. Example: {2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1} = {2, 2, 2}.
I came up with this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter array lenght");
            int arrLenght = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] arr = new int[arrLenght];
            Console.WriteLine("Enter array elements");
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                if (arr[i] == arr[i + 1] && arr[i] == arr[i + 2])
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Maximal sequence of numbers is: {0},{1},{2}",arr[i],arr[i+1],arr[i+2]);
                    break;
                }

            }
```

This works only if the sequence is exactly 3 numbers long. I have to search the array and find the largest sequence but i don't know how to code this. I'm sorry if the question is silly but i am a newbie and i couldn't find solution anywhere else. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for elegance then use Linq

```
var seq = new int[] {2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1};

int[] max = seq.Select((n, i) => new { Value = n, Index = i})
    .OrderBy(s => s.Value)
    .Select((o, i) => new { Value = o.Value, Diff = i - o.Index } )
    .GroupBy(s => new { s.Value, s.Diff})
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
    .First()
    .Select(f => f.Value)
    .ToArray();
```

That's why I ♥ Linq

Comment: LINQ is basicly SQL in C# right? It makes life a lot easier :)

Comment: No. Linq is a language of itself. However you can use Linq to SQL to run SQL queries from Linq. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976.aspx. Also make sure you accept an answer so that people know this is closed.

Answer (score 2):

With Linq:

```
int count = seq.Count();
int[] maxSeq = seq
    .Select((i, index) => new{ 
        Item = i, index,
        PrevEqual = index == 0 || seq.ElementAt(index - 1) == i,
        NextEqual = index == count - 1 || seq.ElementAt(index + 1) == i,
    })
    .Where(x => x.PrevEqual || x.NextEqual)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Item)
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
    .First().Select(x => x.Item).ToArray();
```

**Explanation**.

- select an anonymous type with a `bool` property that indicates if it's the same value as the previous
- since we're only interested in those, restrict the query with `Where`
- `GroupBy` the elements with equal values
- then order by the count of each group(descending)
- select the values of the first group(the largest)
- create a new array from the values

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/3AIemX)

Comment: This algorithm does not work when the max sequence is at the end of the sequence. Example: { 2, 1, 1, 1 }

Comment: @AndreaAngella: Good catch. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Without completely giving you the answer to your question I can suggest that you take a look at LINQ as there would definitely be some simple ways of figuring this out. You could start by looking at the `Group`, `Count`, `OrderBy` and `Select` extension methods which could get you the answer.

Comment: I haven't learned those yet but I will look into them. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Since that is a homework maybe there is a need to build an algorythm

```
        int[] arr = new int[30];//your array
        Random rand = new Random(100);
        int maxCount = 0, curCount, value = 0;          

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            arr[i] = rand.Next(15);//fill the aray with random values               


        arr = arr.OrderBy(a => a).ToArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            curCount = 1;//found new value. and now count == 1
            for (int j = i+1/*search from next array element*/; 
                     j < arr.Length-1/*to the end*/; 
                     j++)
                    {
                        if (arr[i] == arr[j])
                            curCount++;//counts the count
                        else
                            break;//met new value
                    }
                    if (curCount > maxCount)//we've found new sequence 
                {
                    maxCount = curCount;//new sequence length
                    value = arr[i];//sequence values
                    i += maxCount;//we don't need to watch the sequence again


                }
        }
```

I have no VS in my hands right now to check this, so I hope that works =) Anyway there is an idea

Answer (score 0):

Try with this method:

```
int MaximimalSequence<T>(IList<T> list, out T value)
{
    T aux = default(T);
    value = default(T);
    int max = 0, hist = 0;
    bool first = true;

    foreach (var i in list)
    {
        if (!first && aux.Equals(i))
        {
            max++;
        }
        else
        {
            first = false;
            max = 1;
        }

        if (hist < max)
        {
            hist = max;
            value = i;
        }

        aux = i;
    }

    return hist;
}
```

To call it:

```
int value;
var maximumSequence = MaximimalSequence<int>(new List<int> { 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1 }, out i);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem that can be solved with a single iteration of the sequence. It is important to make sure that the algorithm works in all the cases, included when the maximal sequence is at the end of the sequence.

```
    private static IEnumerable<int> GetMaxSequence(IList<int> seq)
    {
        if (seq == null || seq.Count == 0)
        {
            return new List<int>();
        }

        int value = seq[0];

        int currentSequenceStartIndex = 0;
        int currentSequenceLength = 1;

        int maxSequenceStartIndex = 0;
        int maxSequenceLength = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < seq.Count; i++)
        {
            if (seq[i] == value)
            {
                currentSequenceLength++;
                continue;
            }

            if (currentSequenceLength > maxSequenceLength)
            {
                maxSequenceLength = currentSequenceLength;
                maxSequenceStartIndex = currentSequenceStartIndex;
            }

            currentSequenceStartIndex = i;
            currentSequenceLength = 1;
            value = seq[i];
        }

        if (currentSequenceLength > maxSequenceLength)
        {
            maxSequenceLength = currentSequenceLength;
            maxSequenceStartIndex = currentSequenceStartIndex;
        }

        return seq.Skip(maxSequenceStartIndex).Take(maxSequenceLength);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    // create two list holding ints. One for the temporary value and one for the longest sequence
    List<int> longestSequence = new List<int>();
    List<int> temp = new List<int>();
    // create count to count how many elements are holding the same value
    // and counter to assign this value when max is reached
    int count = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    // with for loop compare every element with the elements that follow it
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        int nextElement = i+1;    // element that follows
        count = 0;                // ignore for now see the end of the for loop
        temp.Clear();             // ignore for now see the end of the for loop
        temp.Add(arr[i]);         // add the compared element in to the temp list
        // while the value is the same as following element add this to the temporary list
        // and add count (count++)
        while (arr[i] == arr[nextElement])
        {
            temp.Add(arr[nextElement]);
            nextElement++;
            count++;
        }
        // after that see if the count is bigger than counter (maximum amount of elements so far)
        // it is set to 0 at the beginning
        if (count > counter)
        {
            longestSequence.Clear();
            // if it is bigger assign count value to counter
            counter = count;
            // and copy the temporary list to the longestSequence list
            for (int k = 0; k < temp.Count; k++)
            {
                longestSequence.Add(temp[k]);
            }
        } 
    // at the beggining of the for loop the count will be set to 0 again
    // and the temporary list will be cleared
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    // print the longestSequence list
    foreach (int element in longestSequence)
    {
        Console.Write(element + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
```

Comment: Some descriptive text about your approach would be nice.

Comment: I have edited the answer and added comments explaining the approach. If additional explanation needed let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
    static int num;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] array;
        Console.Write("enter the size of array : ");
        int input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        int[] temp;
        temp = new int[10];

        int a = 0;
        int count = 0;

        array = new int[input];

        for (int i = 0; i < input; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("enter value ( " + i + ", " + input+") :");
            array[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < array.Length; j++)
            {
                if (i == array[j])//compare i with array
                {
                    count++;
                    if (a < count)//if greator found
                    {

                        a = count;
                        num = i;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    count = 0;
                }
            }   
        }
        Console.WriteLine(num +" repeated " + a +" times");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

//programmer : Hamza Jany
//P - Lang = C#

```
    static int num;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] array;
        Console.Write("enter the size of array : ");
        int input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        int[] temp;
        temp = new int[10];

        int a = 0;
        int count = 0;

        array = new int[input];

        for (int i = 0; i < input; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("enter value ( " + i + ", " + input+") :");
            array[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < array.Length; j++)
            {
                if (i == array[j])//compare i with array
                {
                    count++;
                    if (a < count)//if greator found
                    {

                        a = count;
                        num = i;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    count = 0;
                }
            }   
        }
        Console.WriteLine(num +" repeated " + a +" times");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    int[] array1 = { 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1 };
    int start = 0;
    int length  = 0;
    int bestStart = 0;
    int bestLength = int.MinValue;
    for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if ((i == 0) || (array1[i] != array1[i - 1]))
            {
                start = i;   
            }
            if(array1[start] == array1[start + 1])
            {
                length++;
                if (length > bestLength)
                {
                    bestLength = length;
                    bestStart = start;
                }         
            }
            else
            {
                length = 0;
            }
        }
       Console.Write("The best sequence is :");
       for (int i = bestStart; i < bestLength + bestStart; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(" " + array1[i]);             
        }
 }
 /* 
     This will give : The best sequence is : 2 2 2 2 
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is my solution to the problem in C#. I tried to put as less code as possible to make it more readable and understandable.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] intList = new int[] { 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5 };

        foreach (var item in intList) {
            Console.Write(item + " ");
        }

        #region Calculating sequence and printing details
        int length = 1, start = 0, finalIndx = 0,
        bigSeqNum = 0, finalLen = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < intList.Length; i++) {
            if (intList[i] == intList[start]) {
                length++;
                if (length > finalLen) {
                    finalLen = length;
                    finalIndx = start;
                    bigSeqNum = intList[start];
                }
            } else {
                start = i;
                length = 1;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nBig Seq. Num: " + bigSeqNum);
        Console.WriteLine("Start index: " + finalIndx);
        Console.WriteLine("Length: " + finalLen);
        Console.WriteLine();
        #endregion
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("enter length of the array");
            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] myarray = new int[n];
            for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("enter value of array" + " " + i);
                myarray[i]=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            int length = 1;
            int start = 0;
            int bestlength=0;
            int beststart=0;
            for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
            {
                if (myarray[i - 1] == myarray[i])
                {
                    length++;
                    continue;
                }
                if (bestlength<length)
                {
                    bestlength = length;
                    beststart = start;
                }
                length = 1;
                start = i;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("the best sequence is");

            for (int j = beststart; j < bestlength + beststart; j++)
            {


                Console.Write(myarray[j] + ",");

            }


        }
    }
}
```