# Append elements to a List<int> until a specified value is input?

Tags: c#, list

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();

    do
    {
        numbers.Add(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
    } 
    while ();
```

I'm trying to solve the following problem: Write a program that finds the maximal sequence of equal elements in an array.
        Example: {2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1} --> {2, 2, 2}.

So I want to begin with inputting the elements of the list because I don't want to specify the length of the sequence beforehand in order to make it work for any given length.

I would like to make it stop appending more elements to the list when a specific value (such as -1, or a comma, or something) is input. I've come up with the code above, and I just need to find out what condition to use in order to fulfill my idea. Maybe I need a whole different approach... You tell me.

Comment: Save the input in a variable and check it in the condition..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this: read Console until the special string is read; try parse otherwise:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
  List<int> numbers = new List<int>();

  while (true) {
    String line = Console.ReadLine();

    // Put here your condition(s) to break the input: -1, comma... 
    if (String.Equals(line, "-1", StringComparison.Ordinal))
      break;

    int v;

    if (int.TryParse(line, out v))
      numbers.Add(v);
    else 
      Console.WriteLine("Sorry, this incorrect number is ignored.");
  }

  // You've done with the input: numbers contains all the integers you have to analyze
  ... 
}
```

P.S. Actually, to solve the problem you *don't need* `List<int>`: you can do with the length of the maximal sequence so far (and the number which repeats within it); and current sequence length and number which repeats within it

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Then anything other than a number will break the loop.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
    int inputNumber;

    while (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out inputNumber))
    {
        numbers.Add(inputNumber);
    }
}
```

If you want to break the loop when the value is `-1` you can simply add an `if`:

```
while (...)
{
    if (inputNumber == -1) break;
    ...
}
```

As for "maximal sequence of equal elements in an array" you can check existing solutions

- [maximal sequence of equal elements in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13745241/340760)

Comment: +1 for clarity but you forgot about terminating condition with -1

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
int newInt = -1;
while(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out newInt) && newInt > -1)
{
  numbers.Add(newInt)
}
```

You don't need a do-while becuase you only need the code inside the while-loop to run if the condition is met.
Also [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is very handy in this senario, as it will return `true` if the string input can be converet to an int. It also hands you the int it converted via the `out newInt` putting the value into the variable `newInt`